# Set different imageEdgeInsets for different states of UIButton in iOS 5

Tags: image, ios5, uibutton

How can I set different imageEdgeInsets for different states of UIButton ? 
e.g

```
    // For UIControlStateHighlighted state
UIEdgeInsets checkedImageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, -10, -90, -50);
cell.firstElementButton.imageEdgeInsets = checkedImageInsets;
[cell.firstElementButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:CHECKBOX_CHECKED_IMAGE] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

// For UIControlStateNormal state
UIEdgeInsets uncheckedImageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, -50, -10, -50);
cell.firstElementButton.imageEdgeInsets = uncheckedImageInsets;
[cell.firstElementButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:CHECKBOX_UNCHECKED_IMAGE] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Does anybody know about this? Thanks